# Very small transformer powering a microwave oven

Tags: transformer, mains, magnetics

I have recently cannibalized a 6 year old microwave oven. 
I was very surprised to find the following beast at the electrical entry of the oven:

[image: photo of tiny transformer on small circuit board]

The reason: this small 1:1 isolation transformer was powering a 900W oven, without any switching technology (everything in the circuit remains at the main 50Hz): the big internal high voltage transformer was connected to it. 
I have analysed the circuit and drawn the schematic:

[image: schematic showing transformer with very few other compoonents]

If I'm not wrong, the blue cubic component is a capacitor, and so are the two other small blue components (as indicated in the schematic). I guess that the resistor is a bleeder, and that the tank LC circuit is tuned to resonate at 50Hz (in order to block the current in the case where the secondary is opened). 
I would like to know if I am missing something, and if not, if this is a well known technique to reduce the size of the transformer connected to the mains supply. Also, what is the essential reason this thing was inserted here? Galvanic isolation?

Comment: Could you double-check your reverse engineering, and check winding connections? The circuit is more likely a common-mode filter, to prevent high-frequency noise from entering AC mains.

Comment: Are you asking where the wires were connected, or if my analyse of the circuit is wrong?

Comment: The AC line is connected to the fuse and to the node you labelled OUT1.  As Richard already pointed out it's a common-mode choke for conducted EMI purposes.  As you suspected there's no way a microwave oven is being powered by using it as a transformer.

Comment: I am sure you got the connection of those coupled inductors wrong. The voltage of 220V cannot be possible handled by such small magnetic core and such small winding.

Comment: Ali and John, thank you for your remarks; this is probably a mistake, despite I was sure to note this carefully.

Comment: If it was actually connected that way, the fuse would blow instantly. Rotate the choke 90° so the two coils are in series with the respective lines and with dots at the same end.

Comment: I thought it is technically possible to tune LC circuit to block the current when the secondary is left open (say), so the fuse would not blow. But as I wrote, people here have convinced me this is a mistake of mine, and that the beast is simply a RFI filter.

Comment: I recommend you not erase the question. Don't you think someone else will have the same question?  Many Q-and-A's revolve around an initial misunderstanding.   In your case you "knew" it was a transformer, and from there, it was just too easy to draw what you thought you were seeing.

Comment: Good question. Problem was in tracing the cct. Good learnung exercise. 
See [this cct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOUhq.jpg)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you double-check your wiring diagram you will find that is NOT a transformer. That is a common mode choke to keep RFI from being transmitted out through the mains power cord.

There is no way (with currently-known technology) to make a mains-frequency transformer that small that handles as much current as a microwave oven draws. You have seen how big the transformer needs to be by your comparison with the size of the high-voltage transformer.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_(electronics)#Common-mode_chokes

Comment: OK, it is too late to check again where were the wires  connected: I noted this on the board as I cut the wires; I was sure this was correct, but this is apparently a mistake. Too late to erase this question too.

Comment: @MikeTeX I say leave it; see my comment under the question itself.

Answer (score 20):

As an amplification of Richard Crowley's answer, I'd do this in a comment but there is no way to include a circuit diagram. Your circuit actually looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp1qIA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

as far as the "transformer" is concerned. As stated, it's a common-mode filter which keeps the microwave from driving noise onto the power lines.

<strike>Most likely, R1 is a PTC surge preventer, although this is not guaranteed.</strike>
R1 (the resistor clearly visible in the OP photo with a green multiplier band) will be across C3 and is likely intended to bleed any residual voltage from it after AC supply is removed.